# java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child() .... APP IS CRASHING

Tags: java, android, firebase

My app is crashing...

I'm not able to understand why iS  it is giving this error and how can i remove this error so the app starts working.

in the logcat it states:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()

2020-08-19 02:44:21.603 25163-25282/com. E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.

My activity:

```
      public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private NavigationView navigationView;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
private RecyclerView postList;
private Toolbar mToolbar;

private CircleImageView NavProfileImage;
private TextView NavProfileUserName;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DatabaseReference UsersRef;

String CurrentUserID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    CurrentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawable_layout);
    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity.this, drawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_closed);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

    View navView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.navigation_header);
    NavProfileImage = (CircleImageView) navView.findViewById(R.id.nav_profile_image);
    NavProfileUserName = (TextView) navView.findViewById(R.id.nav_user_full_name);

    UsersRef.child(CurrentUserID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {

                if (snapshot.hasChild("fullname")) {
                    String fullname = snapshot.child("fullname").getValue().toString();
                    NavProfileUserName.setText(fullname);
                }

                if (snapshot.hasChild("profileimage")) {
                    String image = snapshot.child("profileimage").getValue().toString();
                    Picasso.get().load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_profile_pic_grey).into(NavProfileImage);
                }

                else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Profile name does not exist...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            UserMenuSelector(item);

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

my logcat:

```
     2020-08-19 02:44:21.603 25163-25282/com.app E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
```

2020-08-19 02:44:21.666 25163-25280/com.app V/FA: onActivityCreated
2020-08-19 02:44:21.828 25163-25336/com.appi V/FA: Connecting to remote service
2020-08-19 02:44:21.887 25163-25336/com.app V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-08-19 02:44:21.949 25163-25336/? V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-08-19 02:44:21.953 25163-25163/? W/ActionBarDrawerToggle: DrawerToggle may not show up because NavigationIcon is not visible. You may need to call actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
2020-08-19 02:44:21.969 25163-25163/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
2020-08-19 02:44:21.969 25163-25163/? D/MMListParser: onlineVersion -1 defaultVersion 20191101
2020-08-19 02:44:21.970 25163-25163/? D/mmscene: open server config failed /data/oppo/multimedia/oppo_display_perf_list.xml
2020-08-19 02:44:21.971 25163-25163/? D/mmscene: getHint applicationScene=com.appinion,idx=0 none
2020-08-19 02:44:21.981 25163-25163/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-08-19 02:44:21.985 25163-25163/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.app, PID: 25163
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app/com.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3296)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:114)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:74)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1994)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:500)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:913)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()
at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(DatabaseReference.java:96)
at com.appinion.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:72)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7337)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7328)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3126)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3296) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:114) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:74) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1994) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:500) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:913) 
2020-08-19 02:44:21.999 25163-25163/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 25163 SIG: 9

TELL ME WHERE I'M GOING WRONG...
please help me.....

thanks...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67449449/4828650

Answer (score 4):

The error message is telling you that you passed `null` in a call to `child()`.  You have only one place in your code where a null value is possible:

```
UsersRef.child(CurrentUserID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

This means `CurrentUserID` is null at the time you used it here.  This means that `mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()` is null at the time you called it.  Which means a user was not signed in at that time.  You should check for null before using it like this.

Comment: actually that error is coming as current user id id null... so i need a way to check that it is not null.... please help me

Comment: so the error is somewhere along the lines :      mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    CurrentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");